# Google place autocomplete language

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm using the google places autocomplete.

The source code is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I noticed that when the browser is in english it return the results in english, and when the browser is in hebrew it returns the results in hebrew.

I want all the results to return in hebrew no matter what the browser language is.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the language-parameter when you load the API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&language=iw
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport